# VBA Printing the value in a textBox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to print the value of a textbox in excel using VBA. The textbox is title "TextBox 6" and this is the code I used:

```
Debug.Print (wSheet.Shapes("TextBox 6").TextFrame.Characters.Text)
```

wSheet is the main worksheet where the textbox is located. The error I get is:

> The item with the specified name wasn't found.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using userforms?

Comment: @KiranMaroju No I am not using userforms

Comment: this worked for me;wSheet.Shapes("TextBox 6").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ActiveX Controls. Add a textbox to the sheet.
[image]

Right click in textbox and select the view code menu

[image]

Then try the following code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Cells(1).Value = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the name of the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub this()
    Debug.Print ; ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Value
End Sub
```